# Is changing css styles via 'document.getElementById(o).style[p]=v' valid?

Tags: javascript, css, function

We are hoping on trimming some fat from our custom library we use across our products.

One commonly used action is changing of object styles.

Normally, we do this via:

```
document.getElementById('object').style.property='value';
```

I just tested the following in chromes console, and it worked:

```
function objStyle(o,p,v){
    document.getElementById(o).style[p]=v;
}

objStyle('object','property','value');
```

Is this a valid way of doing things?

Any pitfalls one can think of when using this way of doing things? Crossbrowser compatability?

Comment: You should use jQuery! `$('#object').css('property', 'value');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly valid. A property that you access by `.name` can also be access by `['name']`.

That works for any property in any object, for example:

```
window['alert']('Hello world.');

document['getElementById']('object')['style']['color'] = '#fff';
```

Comment: Thank you whole heartedly Guffa. Have to wait 8 minutes to accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.

One thing I would consider though is whether you want to keep calling `document.getElementById()` (inside the function) if there is a situation where you need to perform multiple changes to the same element. What I'm about to suggest is overkill for the sake of showing you more options, but consider that you can pass the Id to your function, or pass a reference to the element directly, or have a function that accepts a string or an element reference and figures it out from the type of the parameter:

```
function objStyleById(oId,p,v){
   document.getElementById(oId).style[p]=v;
}

function objStyle(o,p,v) {
   o.style[p] = v;
}

function objStyleAuto(o,p,v) {
   if (typeof o === "string")
      o = document.getElementById("o");
   // else not a string so assume o is element reference
   o.style[p] = v;
}

objStyleById('object','property','value');

var myEl = document.getElementById("someElement");
objStyle(myEl,"prop","val");
objStyle(myEl,"prop2","val");
// some other non-style operation on myEl, e.g.,
myEl.className = "something";
myEl.innerHTML = "something";
objStyle(myEl.parentNode,"prop","value");

objStyleAuto('object','property','value');
objStyleAuto(myEl,'property','value');
```

Comment: picked the answer above only because he answered first and i already said i would pick his ;)

Comment: No problem, Guffa knows his stuff (and actually I already upvoted his answer), but I thought you might like a couple of other ideas to work with to take the original idea a bit further.